# How to access private ip address

Tags: java, android

I have my laptop that is connected to Internet through my Android mobile which is having its hotspot application running. Now my laptop must have been provided with private ip and my mobile is using a public ip address. I am running a web server on this laptop. Now how can I access this web server from my friends laptop which is not a part of the network ?
I mean which ip address should I provide private ip of the laptop or the public ip address of my mobile?

Comment: `Public IP` is what you provide to your friend, and you will `forward the port on the router`, to send any request for the server to your `Laptop` :-) This is the same way I am hosting my own site, from my personal computer for free :-) But since you mentioned a mobile phone, in between, I guess you won't have privilege to forward port on your mobile phone (just guessing) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Access the Website outside the Network, you have to use the public ip. 
With the private ip you just can Access ist within Your Network.

I recommend you to get a webserver, because your public ip changes with every reconnect, but at least onces in 24h. And most phone providers do not allow server hosting.

Answer (score 2):

First your need to find out the following two information:

- Your laptop's private IP on which your web server listens on.  Use `ipconfig` on windows or `ifconfig` on linux or mac.
- Your public IP (If you don't know how to find this, you could navigate to [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) and it will show you your public IP)

Then setup a port forwarding rule in your router that forwards a port to your laptop's web server's port.  It's not a good idea to forward any port to your laptop, so pick one port.  This can be the same port as the port your webserver is configured to listed on.

Lets say you have your web server running on 8080 on your laptop, you would setup a port forwarding rule that maps source port 8080 to your laptop's private ip on port 8080.

You then use the public ip along with the port from outside your internal network.  E.g. `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080`